# Find numbers between 1 and 10000 whose sum of digits are prime

Tags: c, primes

I have the following C code that finds numbers between 1 and 10000 whose sum of digits are prime and save then to a file.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int sum_of_digits(int);
int check_prime(int);
void save_to_file(int);

int main()
{
    int i, num, isPrime;
    for(i=2; i<=10000; i++)
    {
        num = sum_of_digits(i);
        isPrime = check_prime(num);
        if(isPrime)
        {
            printf("%d ", i);
            save_to_file(i);
        }
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}

int sum_of_digits(int num)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (num != 0)
    {
        sum += num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

int check_prime(int num)
{
    int i;
    for (i=2; i<=num-1; i++)
    {
        if (num%i == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    if (i == num)
        return 1;
}

void save_to_file(int num)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("prime.txt","a+");
    fprintf(fp, "%d ", num);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The sum of the digits is such a small number (9+9+9+9=36 the maximum in your case) that you can even hard-code the values which are prime or not:

```
//number:         1  2  3  4  5  6  7
char isPrime[] = {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ...}
```

But lets assume you don't go that far. The next best thing would be to generate such an array at run-time before your main loop (also based on the fact that the largest number you need to check if it's a prime is very small). A popular method for doing this is the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Thus, you can now look up if the sum of the various digits is a prime or not in constant time:

```
if (isPrime[sum_of_digits(i)])
{
    //...
}
```

As to writing the results to a file, I would keep the file open for the duration of the loop. This improves efficiency by sending bigger chunks of data to the disk thanks to buffering.

Answer (score 1):

**No return path**.

Example, with `check_prime(1)`, no value is returned leading to undefined behavior.

```
int check_prime(int num) {
    int i;
    for (i=2; i<=num-1; i++) {
        if (num%i == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    if (i == num)
        return 1;

    // missing return
    return 0; // recommended

}
```

Per the code use of `check_prime()`, such an event is not expected to happen.   Yet functions, unless `static` and heavily documented to detail their limited range, should be more robust.  Also, unusual optimizations have been known to occur when code has a path that leads to UB.

Any `num < 2` value has trouble.  `num==INT_MIN` leads to another undefined behavior with `num-1`.

Consider making functions like `check_prime(int num)` to have *some* defined behavior over all the range of `INT_MIN <= num <= INT_MIN` or document its limitations.

```
int check_prime_suggested(int num) {
    int i;
    for (i=2; i < num; i++) {  // avoid num-1 which may overflow
        if (num%i == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return i == num;
}
```

In a **similar** line-of-thought, `int sum_of_digits(int num)` has negative results when `num < 0`.  Document the limitations of the intended use of the code or make it so code is well defined and correct functionality for all input values.

Better to **check the results** of `fopen()` before using.  Use `assert()` or better yet, add test code.

```
#include <assert.h>

void save_to_file(int num) {
  FILE *fp;
  fp=fopen("prime.txt","a+"); 
  assert(fp);
```

Use **entire range** of task.  We *know* `1` does not pass the test, well neither does 10000 and 9999.  Should we code [2 to 9998]?  The point is the *contract* was for numbers [1...10000] and code should clearly demonstrate that:

```
// for(i=2; i<=10000; i++)
for(i=1; i<=10000; i++)
```